# How to make a direct link to a file that I can change?

Tags: download

How can I make a direct link to download a file and so when I change/update the file it won't change the link (so it stays the same).

Sorry if I sound confusing! But I want this done maybe in Dropbox, Google Drive, Mega etc. (anything that can upload files).

Example: If I make this a direct link to a file download - http://downloadexample.com/download/file.rar or something like that, how would I change the file in the download without it affecting the link so it stays the same and you can always access it no matter if I change what it downloads.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: I'm using it for making an auto-updating feature on my program in C#, but I didn't mention that before, sorry.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I dont think it makes any difference as long as you don't change the file name on the server.

Comment: Oh yeah, that works. I also found this feature on Google Drive to add versions of a file, I might see if that works.